# Can't boot to installed Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 14.04

I tried to install another OS on my computer, but something terrible happened. Now I can't boot into installed Ubuntu. I tried to install Ubuntu on another partition, it succeed. But after rebooting, it automatically boots into USB installation, can not read installed systems. At the boot menu, I can't select booting OS as 1st boot option, or 2nd! It always boots into USB and if USB is not plugged in, it  shows errors and doesn't open anything. My computer is Asus. I don't know what actually is it's model.
--- my father solved the problem, thanks for the support. If you live the same issue, try to reset boot settings to default :) ---

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 contains the tools to fix this problem. I will need to go back and take a look, but gparted, grub and bootrepair should provide the arsenal to fix this.

I think Boot Repair may be what you  are looking for. I remember I needed this to recover from a similar problem...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

m2k1981's answer is also the best first step to take....

Other: Boot into the USB and run gparted (if not on the distro then get to terminal and run sudo 
apt-get install gparted to take a look at what is going on but note: Editing partitions has the potential to cause LOSS of DATA.

Answer (score 0):

After press power button to start computer press F2 or delete button to go to BIOS and change **BOOTING SEQUENCE**. Generally you can find booting sequence under Advance or Boot tab. Make HDD first booting device where you have installed your os. Save and exit. And **BOOT MENU** list of option shown after F12 is press instead of F2 or delete. Post whatever happens.

Comment: Its the problem, i cant change first booting device from boot menu, the choices are usb and disabling boot(always starts boot menu).

Comment: I tried all chices, both doesnt work, i need to change first bot option but i cant. There wasnt a problem when im installing ubuntu for first time, the problem occoured this time.

Answer (score 0):

After you successfully installed your Ubuntu you needed to unplug the USB because your bios automatically will boot to your USB installation if your USB is still connected.

Boot-repair can help you with your grub which is the boot menu your missing.

You can use your USB and use "try it before installing" it option and try to install the boot-repair from there.

Also if all fails try to reinstall ubuntu but make sure your selecting the options mount point to / root.

Comment: Doesnt work neither.

Comment: what doesn't work? Did you change the Bios order before trying to install boot-repair from your USB Installation? You needed the USB to boot first to do this, then disconnect your USB after boot-repair is done.

Comment: ITS THE PROBLEM! I yried boot repair too. When i unplug the usb and reboot, it says i need to plug a usb to boot. I opened gparted while trying ubuntu from usb, all files are saved, the only problem is booting into os. And i cant choose it as boot order.